# Is a strongly normalized relational database not efficient?

Tags: database, performance, normalization

I was reading this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26398/stackoverflow-database-design-join-issues and I got the following question: using a very normalized db is not efficient?

How should be found the right compromise?

I'm not sure if this question better fits here or on programmer. Here there are some similar but if I should move, just ask me.

Answer (score 9):

Whether it will speed it up or slow it down depends strongly on the nature of the data, the size of the tables, the type of querying, the indexing. I have seen it go both ways although, more often than not in my experience, normalization to the third normal form speeds things up. Relational databases are built to be normalized and designed so that those things are expected.

One thing the denormalization advocates often forget is that speed is critical to transactions (possibly more critical due to blocking potential) and that denormalization often slows down updates. You can't measure performance just on select statements. Denormalized database tables are often wider and wider tables can often cause slowdowns too.

Denormalized databases are a major problem to keep the data integrity in and a change of a company name in a normalized database might result in one record needing to be updated and in a denormalized one might result in 100,000,000 records needing to be updated. That is why denormalization is generally only preferred for databases  (like data warehouses) where the data is loaded through an ETL process but the database itself is frequently queried for complex reporting scenarios. Transactional databases that have a lot of user updates and deletions and inserts are often much faster if they are normalized to the third normal forma at least.  Now you can go crazy with normalization too, don't get me wrong. I shouldn't have to join to 10 tables to get a simple address especially if I get them often. Data that is often used together often belongs together especially if the items are unlikely to change a million records if a change is made. For instance in the address, it would require a large update if Chicago changed it's name to New Chicago, but those types of massive address changes are pretty rare in my part of the world. On the other hand, company name changes are frequent and could cause massive disruption if they needed to be made to millions of denormalized records.

If you are not designing a data warehouse, then normalize your data. Never denormalize unless you are a database specialist with at least 5 years experience in large systems. You can harm things tremendously if you don't know what you are doing. If things are slow denormalization is one of the last performance improvements to try. Generally, the problem is fixed by writing better queries that are sargable and which do not use poorly performing techniques like correlated subqueries or by getting the correct indexing applied.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Every time I've worked to normalize a database, it has **radically** sped up. But, the performance problems with the non-normalized DBs were that they needed many indices, most of which were not used for any particular query, having too many columns, forced DISTINCT constraints on queries that wouldn't have been needed with a normalized DB, and inefficient table searching.

If common queries need to perform many joins on large tables for the simplest of lookups, or hit many tables for writes to update what the user/application sees as an atomic update of a single entity, then as traffic grows, so will that burden, at a rate higher than with lower/no normalization. Typically what happens is that everything runs OK until either the database and application are put on different production servers, while they were on the same dev server, or when the data gets big enough to start hitting the disks all the time.

DBMS products couple logical layout and physical storage, so while it may be as likely to increase speed as decrease it, normalization of base tables will in some way affect performance of the system.

Usually, the right compromise is views, with an SQL DBMS. If you are using any variation of design by contract, views are likely the correct design decision  even without any concerns for normalization or performance, so that the application gets a model fitting its needs. Scalability concerns, like for major websites, create problems that don't have quick and easy solutions, at this point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Normalization optimizes storage requirements and data consistency. As a tradeoff, it can make queries more complex and slow.

> How should be found the right compromise?

Unfortunately, that cannot be answered with generality.

It all depends on your application and its requirements.

If your queries run too slow, and indexing or caching or query rewriting or database parameter tuning don't cut it, denormalization may be appropriate for you.

(OTOH, if your queries run just fine, or can be made to run just fine, there is probably no need to go there).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Thilo's post:
normalizing on SAP HANA is wrong due to the fact the db normalize the data itself. If you do it anyway you will slow down the database.

Comment: HANA is a database by SAP which works in memory only. That's why it is so fast.